# FactoryGirl cannot assign to a enum validated parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, enums, factory-bot

I am using RSpec, FactoryGirl and ActiveRecord. The following test is not passing:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe User, type: :model do
    it "has a valid factory" do
            expect(FactoryGirl.create(:user)).to be_valid
    end
end
```

I have the following error:

```
1) User has a valid factory
 Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.create(:user)).to be_valid
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Role can't be blank
```

I also have the following model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  enum role: [:admin, :student, :school]
  validates :role, presence: true
end
```

And I have the following factory:

```
require 'faker'
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
            sequence(:email) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
            password Faker::Internet.password(8, 16)
            role :student
    end
end
```

However, it passes if I remove the enums in the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates :role, presence: true
end
```

I would like to keep the enum as there is only a set of strings that I would like to allow represent roles.

I would appreciate information that will help me to merge FactoryGirl with the enum correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using at @eugen's answer, I see now that I was supposed to create the column as integer and I had declared it as string:

```
class AddRoleToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :role, :string, null: false
  end
end
```

I ran the following migration to fix my error and it worked:

```
class ChangeRoleRepresentationInTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
      change_column :users, :role, 'integer USING CAST(role AS integer)', null: false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your factory definition for the user, you set the role with `role :student`. Enums are stored as integers, not as strings - in order for your definition to work, you need something like `role User.roles["student"]`.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html for more details.